# How many list can we add inside list in python?

Tags: python, python-3.7

I have declared a list and trying to print it. Here is my code:

```
list1 = ["hello", 23, 5.0, ["hi", 15,[2,3,4,'5',[3,7,8]]], "xyz"]
print(list1[3][2][2][2])
```

And i got the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ASUS/Desktop/Data/tr.py", line 2, in <module>
    print(list1[3][2][2][2])
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 3):

You are pointing to the wrong index. It's not an error about the list declaration. It's an error about your printing. Please read the errors carefully before asking. 
Here is what your print statement points to:

```
list1[3]       -> ["hi", 15,[2,3,4,'5',[3,7,8]]]
list1[3][2]    -> [2,3,4,'5',[3,7,8]]
list1[3][2][2] -> 4
```

So when you try to print `list1[3][2][2][2]` it tries to access 2nd index of int 4. Which is not subscriptable.

Answer (score 0):

Open a REPL and see for yourself!

```
>>> list1 = ["hello", 23, 5.0, ["hi", 15,[2,3,4,'5',[3,7,8]]], "xyz"]
>>> list1[3][2][2]
4
>>> _
```

This is why `list1[3][2][2][2]` ends with an error: `list1[3][2][2]` is not a list.